# Выделить и скопировать в буфер все ячейки Excel, содержащие данные (pywin32)

Tags: windows, python-3.x, winapi

Ребята, используя pywin32, необходимо в открытом Excel файле выбрать все ячейки, содержащие данные. Количество столбцов всегда одно и то же, а вот количество строк меняется. Пробовал через `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select()` - по количеству столбцов всё верно выделяет, а вот у строк захватывает и те, в которых уже нет данных. Как выделить все ячейки и скопировать в буфер всё их содержимое (грубо говоря нажать ctrl+a, затем ctrl+c)?

```
def run_macros(self):
    os.startfile(self.path)
    xl = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
    xl.DisplayAlerts = False
    if self.name == '\Report_PRTO':
        xl.Run("PERSONAL.xlsb!Макрос1")
        xl.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select() #это строка работает некорректно
        xl.ActiveWorkbook.Save()
        xl.Quit()
```

UPD
Разобрался как скопировать нужный диапазон ячеек - надо вместо `xl.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select()` использовать `xl.ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Select()`, теперь вопрос, как скопировать всё выделенное в буфер?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено.

```
def run_macros(self):
os.startfile(self.path)
xl = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
xl.DisplayAlerts = False
if self.name == '\Report_PRTO':
    xl.Run("PERSONAL.xlsb!Макрос1")
    xl.ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Select()
    xl.Selection.Copy()
    xl.ActiveWorkbook.Save()
    xl.Quit()
```